# Why is my int being read as 0 from Azure Table Storage, not as the stored value?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to read values that I have stored in an Azure Storage Table. When I retrieve the entity, in Fiddler, I can see the response as having the correct value, i.e.:

```
{
"odata.etag":"W/\"datetime'2019-01-24T20%3A23%3A58.3605274Z'\"",
"PartitionKey":"0029c461-74b9-47a7-955b-28e07b1905ab",
"RowKey":"09a79860-f568-481c-9641-9a1d53ebd678",
"Timestamp":"2019-01-24T20:23:58.3605274Z",
"AdjustmentId":"[GUID]",
"CompanyName":"[CompanyNme]",
"CustomerId":"[GUID]",
"Date@odata.type":"Edm.DateTime",
"Date":"2019-01-24T20:23:49.9487324Z",
"FinalQuantity":35,
"Id":"[GUID]",
"InitialQuantity":36.0,
"OfferName":"[Product]",
"Requester":"[User]",
"Status":"Accepted",
"StatusMessage":"Created",
"Type":"QuantityAdjustment"
}
```

However, when I work with this resoponse in my C# code, the InitialQuantity is set to 0. I'm using Microsoft Azure WebJobs Extensions Storage v3.0.3 and WindowsAzure.Storage v9.3.3.

The entity class that the Azure Storage SDK maps this to is below:

```cs
public class Transaction : TableEntity, ITransaction
    {
/// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the adjustment identifier.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The adjustment identifier.</value>
        public string AdjustmentId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the name of the company.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The name of the company.</value>
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the customer identifier.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The customer identifier.</value>
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the Transaction's date. Should be generated on creation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The date.</value>
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the final quantity following the transaction.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The final quantity.</value>
        public int FinalQuantity { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the transaction identifier. Should be a GUID in string format. This is
        /// generated when a new Transaction is created.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The identifier.</value>
        public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToLower();

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the initial quantity.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The initial quantity.</value>
        public int InitialQuantity { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the offer identifier.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The offer identifier.</value>
        public string OfferId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the name of the offer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The name of the offer.</value>
        public string OfferName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the requester.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The requester.</value>
        public string Requester { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the status. Set to pending by default.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The status.</value>
        public string Status { get; set; } = TransactionStatus.Pending;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the status message.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The status message.</value>
        public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the type. Should be set using the constants in the <see
        /// cref="T:LicenseAdjustmentManagement.Infrastructure.TransactionTypes"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The type.</value>
        public string Type { get; set; }

public string ToJson()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
}
```

Code that calls the entities.

```cs
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("[ConnectionString]");
var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
var transactionsTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("Transactions");

var query = TableQuery<Transaction>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("Id", QueryComparisons.Equal, "[GUID]"));

var results = await transactionsTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, default(TableContinuationToken)).AsEnumerable();

var transaction = results.First();
```

All the other values are being read correctly, but the InitialValue is always 0. Any suggestions?

Edit: As suggested by KSib below, the InitialValue is being serialized as a `decimal` or `double` so when it's deserialized as an `int`, it recieves the default value of int, `0`. Any idea why this thing is being serialized as a `decimal` when it's declared as in `int`?

Comment: `in my C# code` you forgot to add your code

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to de-serialize a decimal to an int, presumably and instead of throwing an exception I'm going to assume it just sets the property to `default(int)` which is `0`

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Didn't even notice the decimal in the initial quantity. Now I have to figure out why it's being serialized as a decimal in the first place since the model provides an int.